# How does one become a vampire in the universe of Diabolik Lovers?

Tags: diabolik-lovers

How does human turn into vampire in the world of Diabolik Lovers?

We know for a fact

> that Yui is a vampire at the end of the anime.

And that one of the brothers mentioned that

> no bride ever survived long enough to undergo the transformation.

So, is it ever explained in the anime or the VN?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have some part of a vampire in you, etc.

Yui has the heart of Cordelia and the Sakimaki brothers are born because their parents are both vampires. Yui isn't a proper vampire, but because she has Cordelia's heart, she will soon turn into a vampire.